# IE7 form display

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7

Any idea why the form is displaying like this in IE7?  Dev site is at http://0000t93.dev.radiant.net/register/

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Validate first :) 26 errors i get.

Answer (score 0):

You have duplicated `id`'s.  `id`'s need to be unique per element or a browser may ignore subsequent instances.

[http://validator.w3.org](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://0000t93.dev.radiant.net/register/&charset=%28detect%20automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0)